# pyplot.show function in spyder with python 3.4

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm a novice with Python and working through "Machine Learning In Action" by P. Harrington. I'm having issues seeing my plot when using the `pyplot.show()` function. Below is the code that I'm entering in the IPython console on the bottom right of Spyder.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2])

plt.show()
```

After I enter this last line, nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't appear?